# How do I disable Google Translate 'look up details' or just get it to the old look?

Tags: google-translate, brave

I’d say the title pretty much describes whole situation. The problem is that instead of showing translation it shows under the translation in translation tab ‘look up details’ that I am forced to click and it takes a crazy lot of time to load translations compared to the old version of Google Translate where it loads directly all translations and you can view them immediately. I want to revert to the old design of Google translate as this new one this a total trash and takes forever to translate something.
Thanks in advance for help!!!

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around.
In the toolbar when you hit "tr" then enter,  a bookmarked URL will load and it looks like this:

> https://translate.google.ca/?sl=en&tl=fa&op=translate

instead, you can bookmark another URL with detail tab preloaded:

> https://translate.google.ca/details?sl=en&tl=fa&op=translate

Comment: This work around looks pretty good, though I can't make it look like the old one this is better than sticking up with the current one. Delayed Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

One more issue is that saved words are on the right side as well and when you saved a couple of hundred words and want to review them from time to time you have to switch between saved words and description windows which is not convenient. Even more, it doesn't keep the same page for saved words, if you were on 3rd section (reviewing words 30-40) after the details section you will be on the very first page/section again.